# Excel Structured Reference Dynamic Table Name

Tags: excel, memory-management, named-ranges, excel-indirect, structured-references

I've been at this for an hour now and I've ended up going back to using INDIRECT, which I would rather avoid. I feel like there must be a simpler way of using table format to get this done very cleanly, but I can't figure it out!

I have a sheet [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmnh5.png), where I want the yellow area on the right to show me the data from the available choices on the left, based on the value in the orange cell at the top. The top table is called tPeople, and the bottom table is called tPlaces. So if tPeople is entered in the cell, I want the data for that table to show up in the yellow area.

At the moment, I've set a Named Range of rPeople and rPlaces to get this working with an indirect, but I'd rather be actually using the table, and not use the indirect if possible.

=INDEX(INDIRECT($E$1),$F2,G$1)

Thanks!

Comment: Would `OFFSET` work for you? Something like: `=INDEX(OFFSET($A$1,IF($E$1="rPeople",1,IF($E$1="rPlaces",6,NA())),0,3,3),$F2,G$1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done using OFFSET and INDIRECT on the table name. Here TblName is named range for cell I1. One caveat is that the rPeople and rPlaces table **must be on the same row** or the formula will return #Value error. Also [ID] [ID] is required to fix absolute reference for the structured table referencing. See [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/tips-shortcuts/absolute-formula-references-excel-structured-table/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20an%20absolute%20reference%20with%20structured%20references%20you%20need,additional%20and%20duplicate%20column%20reference.&text=Duplicating%20the%20column%20reference%20will,with%20relative%20and%20absolute%20references.).

[image]